# Fast uploading setting in web environment

Tags: java, c++, file-upload, ftp

I have to find a solution for uploading large content (10GB+) to a remote server. The uploader should be managed by a web page.

I didn't find any reliable solutions (or at least concepts) while searching the internet, so I came up with these scenarios. Can you provide any kind of feedback?

At the moment the common solutions in the market:

1. Http upload with post form (deprecated by speed and content size);
2. Flash uploader - create a ftp client, and deliver the content to the server;
3. Flash uploader - socket based transfer - treat the file as an InputStream and sent it through a socket opened with flash.
4. Java applet uploader - use Apache's ftp client, and send the content with ftp.
5. Java network socket - use the JRE to open a socket and send the content through a socket.

There is this other solution of using a c++ ftp client, that will be called from the Java Applet and use the c++ speed advantage (compared to java) to deliver the content.

Which one should be more efficient to deliver the content? Is there any other technology for doing what I'm looking for?

Comment: The only way to know what's best is to benchmark every solution. Without that all discussion can only be theoretical.

Comment: @Joachim you're right though it's very kind of time-consuming to implement all and then test them all. This is why I needed an advice

Comment: I agree. Thankfully some alternatives can be dropped pretty quickly (like the HTTP POST and FTP alternatives.)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg thanks for the feedback, I ended with a Java uploader that streams the content to a FTP port on a server. It quite fast, a single problem though: the solution is not fault tolerant, if the network drops, the uploader will start over again. Is there any way to simulate a resume for the upload, if there is already half of the original file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

The limiting factor on the speed of upload will almost inevitably be the network - not the language you implement it in.

Do not use FTP if you can possibly avoid it.

Invoking an ftp client from an applet regardless of which client it is nor what language you imlpement the applet in is going to have to work outside the sandbox (which is not a trivial problem to work around). Why does it have to be implemented via a web page?

If you've got any control over the client being used, then websockets are probably the most sensible solution - but support is still patchy in browsers. There are lots of flash uploaders already written - and a few java ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you would chose between a Flash based uploader and a Java applet uploader, which one would you prefer? Is there any chance I could use UDP based transfer to maximize the network bandwidth limitation?

Comment: @Xander Be careful if you go the UDP way, as you have to do things like packet retransmission and reordering yourself. While widely used for games, it's mostly for data where a few dropped packages doesn't matter.

Comment: @Xander: No, using UDP will not be faster/more efficient